# Mongodb: store links inside database

Tags: mongodb

How can I retrieve a JSON object from my database and have it render as a clickable link?
When I inspect my JSON object, it looks like this:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5321183a017d19ca5d00000a"
    },
    "title": "test",
    "time_Date": "1394677818224",
    "imageUrl": "test",
    "post": "<a href='http://www.w3schools.com/'>Test</a>"
}
```

My blog fetches this object, but it shows the entire script tag.

Comment: Your blog software is escaping the value of your "post" field. You will need to provide information on what platform you're using and how you're rendering it to a page in order to get a useful answer.

Comment: How did you render this JSON object? I sounds to me that your tag has been escaped (the "<" and ">" are translated to &lt; and &gt;) some where. To make sure, review your source code of the generate html page. Or use element inspector provided by Chrome/Firebug.

Answer (score 1):

Put "\" infront of every special characters in Strings.

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5321183a017d19ca5d00000a"
    },
    "title": "test",
    "time_Date": "1394677818224",
    "imageUrl": "test",
    "post": "<a href='http:\/\/www.w3schools.com\/'>Test</a>"
}
```